# What is the python equivalent of future/promise (threading)?

Tags: python, multithreading, promise, future

I come from the C++ world, and I'm looking for the equivalent of std::future, std::promise in Python. Is there an equivalent mechanism or another method in Python to achieve the same?
I'm aware of asyncio.Future, but I need it for threading not asyncio.

I'm using a third party library (PJSUA2) which I call directly from my main thread, but which send the results in asynchronous callbacks in context of a worker thread created by the library.

Expecting future/promise support in Python, I was hoping to write my application code like this:

```
future = wrap_foo(...)
if (future.get() != expected_result):
  throw Exception(...)

future1 = wrap_foo(...)
future2 = wrap_bar(...)
```

I was planning on wrapping all library asynchronous calls with a **wrap_xxx** function (where the library function is called **xxx**) taking care of creating the future/promise objects.

I need the ability of having multiple futures pending, so I cannot simply make synchronous **wrap_xxx** functions which block until the result is ready.

Comment: Is the C++ world suffering from dangerous climate change caused by extreme human ignorance and denial, too? Tell us more about this place you come from :D

Comment: @Mulan. Want to know more about København?

Answer (score 1):

See the [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) module -

```py
import asyncio

async def main():
    print('hello')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('world')

asyncio.run(main())
```

```
hello
world
```

It supports [coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines) -

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

async def main():
    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")

    await say_after(1, 'hello')
    await say_after(2, 'world')

    print(f"finished at {time.strftime('%X')}")

asyncio.run(main())
```

```
started at 17:13:52
hello
world
finished at 17:13:55
```

And [tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks) -

```py
import asyncio

async def nested():
    return 42

async def main():
    # Schedule nested() to run soon concurrently
    # with "main()".
    task = asyncio.create_task(nested())

    # "task" can now be used to cancel "nested()", or
    # can simply be awaited to wait until it is complete:
    print(await task)

asyncio.run(main())
```

```
42
```

And [Futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future) -

```py
import asyncio

async def set_after(fut, delay, value):
    # Sleep for *delay* seconds.
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)

    # Set *value* as a result of *fut* Future.
    fut.set_result(value)

async def main():
    # Get the current event loop.
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    # Create a new Future object.
    fut = loop.create_future()

    # Run "set_after()" coroutine in a parallel Task.
    # We are using the low-level "loop.create_task()" API here because
    # we already have a reference to the event loop at hand.
    # Otherwise we could have just used "asyncio.create_task()".
    loop.create_task(
        set_after(fut, 1, '... world'))

    print('hello ...')

    # Wait until *fut* has a result (1 second) and print it.
    print(await fut)

asyncio.run(main())
```

```
hello ...
... world
```

Comment: I fail to see how asyncio is applicable to my situation. I need to pass information from one thread to another. The library is imposing threading on me.

Comment: You need to pass info from thread to thread and the library is imposing threads on you? Coroutines can run arbitrary code and communicate with each other. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I'm using a library (pjsua2) which starts it's own thread from where I get callbacks (regular function calls). I need to transfer those events to the main thread where they can be processed.

Answer (score 1):

C++ std::async library is different from python Asyncio. Unlike Asyncio, which uses an Event Loop on a single thread, C++ async library starts each task on an individual thread (unless std::launch::deferred parameter is passed). As such, communication between tasks in asyncio is not between multiple tasks running on different threads, but between multiple tasks running on the same thread.

Unfortunately, Python does not currently offer the same communication that std::future library does in C++. There are some establishes practices though:

1. Interthread communication through pass by reference variables - use Queue from the Queue library as it is thread safe.

A GUI app using python threading would look like the following:

Thread 1 checks Queue for commands and updates the GUI.

Threads 2 (3, 4, 5...) respond to user GUI interaction, do whatever work they have to do and when finished, push their result to the Queue.

Thread 1 then updates the GUI of the user.

P.S. Since on Python only one thread is running at any given time (the scheduler swaps which thread is running quite frequently, so GUI apps, I/O is ok, but no real thread paralellism), using threading and asyncio (event loop running on one thread, meaning you do not get the benefit of paralellism but you do not block on an I/O operation) is not good for performance intensive operations and one would not receive any speed benefit. If paralellism is required, one should use the Multiprocessing library.